# Why do I have a zero in my $ _GET variable when I rewrite URLs?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I post here because despite the many topics on the net I have not managed to solve my problem.

I concise a website, and to optimize SEO, I must make the URL Rewriting.

I have GET variables passing in the URL and some have spaces that are encoded in the URL by "%20", for example:

```
mapage.php?produit=aménagements%20bois
```

So I apply my rewrite rule in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^ma-page-amenagements-bois$ mapage.php?produit=aménagements%20bois  [L]
```

The problem is that URL rewriting worked but a zero appears in my variable $ _GET instead of space ("aménagements0bois" instead of "aménagements bois") when I try the new URL, which distorts the dynamic display of my page.

I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Is it not better to identify a product by an ID instead of by the name? If the name changes your link would break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add encoded characters in your rewrite rule, you can escape spaces with `\`:

```
RewriteRule ^ma-page-amenagements-bois$ mapage.php?produit=aménagements\ bois  [L]
```

The reason you get a `0` in your url is because apache uses `%1`, `%2`, ... as rewrite variables. And because you don't have a `%2`, only the `0` remains.